# package xassoccnt generating error on \label{} command

Tags: undefined, control, xassoccnt

I'm trying to use the package `xassoccnt`, but it generates the following error:

> Undefined control sequence. \label{...}.

Here below is the file I have runned with TeXstudio, using PDFLaTeX as default compilation (but using LateX as default compilation generates the same error).

1. When I run it as it is below, on the first run there are several error messages (I don't know why), but then it runs without any error.
2. When I run it *after having removed the commands* `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}` on lines 18 and 20, then I get the error message

> Undefined control sequence. \label{...}

on lines 86 and 128.

Here my *.tex file:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
% Sur TeXstudio: Production/Compilation par défaut: PDFLaTeX

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Préambule
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Packages
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{comment}

% Pour le français
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{comment}
\usepackage{xassoccnt} % commande \TotalValue{totalpages}
\end{comment}
\begin{comment}
\DeclareTotalAssociatedCounters{page}{totalpages}
\end{comment}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Commandes de titre (À ADAPTER)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\author{Robin Pereboom}
\newcommand{\session}{mars 2019}
\newcommand{\DureePartOne}{25 minutes}
\newcommand{\DureePartTwo}{35 minutes}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Début du document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

%%%% Nombre total de pages; package xassoccnt; commande \TotalValue{totalpages}
\begin{comment}
The number of pages in this beautiful document: \TotalValue{totalpages} pages! 
\end{comment}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% TEXTE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% PREMIÈRE PARTIE - BEGIN
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{center}
    {\LARGE \textbf{Examen d'admission: session \session}}\\
    \vspace{2.\baselineskip}
    \uppercase{\textbf{\huge Mathématiques}}\\
    {\textbf{\LARGE Première partie, sans calculatrice}}\\
    \vspace{2.\baselineskip}
    \framebox[\textwidth][l]{
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            Durée de l'épreuve: &première partie: \DureePartOne\\
            &seconde partie: \DureePartTwo\\
            &total: 60 minutes\\
            \\
            Ouvrages et matériel autorisés: &\parbox[t]{9cm}{règle graduée, compas et rapporteur}\\
            \\
            Barème: & 50 points au total\\
            \\
            Nombres de pages incluant celle-ci: &première partie: \pageref{LastPagePart01} pages\\
            & seconde partie: \pageref{LastPagePart02} pages\\
            & total: XX pages\\
        \end{tabular}
    }
    
\end{center}

\newpage

\part*{\LARGE{Première partie, sans calculatrice}}
BLABLABLA PREMIÈRE PARTIE 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% PREMIÈRE PARTIE - END
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\label{LastPagePart01}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% SECONDE PARTIE - BEGIN
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newpage
~
\vspace{1.\baselineskip}
\begin{center}
    {\LARGE \textbf{Examen d'admission: session \session}}\\
    \vspace{2.\baselineskip}
    \uppercase{\textbf{\huge Mathématiques}}\\
    {\textbf{\LARGE Seconde partie, avec calculatrice}}\\
    \vspace{2.\baselineskip}
    \framebox[\textwidth][l]{
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            Durée de l'épreuve: &première partie: \DureePartOne\\
            &seconde partie: \DureePartTwo\\
            &total: 60 minutes\\
            \\
            Ouvrages et matériel autorisés: &\parbox[t]{5cm}{machine à calculer (calculatrice autorisée : Casio fx-85, TI-30 (mais non TI-30X PRO) ou modèle équivalent; en aucun cas une calculatrice graphique, programmable ou permettant de résoudre des équations ne sera autorisée), règle graduée, compas et rapporteur}\\
            \\
            Barème: & 50 points au total\\
            \\
            Nombres de pages incluant celle-ci: &première partie: \pageref{LastPagePart01} pages\\
            & seconde partie: \pageref{LastPagePart02} pages\\
            & total: XX pages\\
        \end{tabular}
    }
    
\end{center}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\newpage

\part*{\LARGE{Seconde partie, avec calculatrice}}
BLABLABLA SECONDE PARTIE

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% SECONDE PARTIE _ END
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\label{LastPagePart02}

\end{document}
```

My idea is to get automatically the number of pages of the first part (here 2), the number of pages of the second part (here 2), and the total number of pages (here XX, which I would like to replace by the command `\TotalValue{totalpages}`).

Do someone have a solution for this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I removed all `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}` instructions and got no error.

Comment: I get no error from the MWE: Neither with `comment` present nor with it commented out or removed (it didn't matter whether it was the first or a subsequent LaTeX run, but of course you may get warnings about as of yet undefined labels on a first run: those warnings are normal and should go away after the requested subsequent LaTeX run).

Comment: Then why do I get errors? Did I set the options of TeXstudio wrong?

Comment: A missing `}` can cause unexpected errors, and the `.aux` file can carry them into the next run. (I often type `|` instead of `}`, for example.) Your code as posted compiles fine. I have not been able to create the specific `\label` error in particular by removing a `}` here and there at random, but plenty of other messages depending on which `}` was missing. Note also, doing `]` instead of `}` or vice versa also causes error cascades. Often the distance between the incorrect character and the failing line is quite large.

Comment: Does the code as posted here reproduce the error for you? Can you show us the error message from the `.log` file?

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! My LaTeX distribution was not up to date. I uninstalled and reinstalled the whole (MiKTeX and TeXstudio), and now my MWE doesn't generate any more error.